# Routes marking in android Google Maps

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How do I add a custom route in android using google maps. I am building an app similar to mapmyhike. Is it possible in Maps API V3?

Comment: http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html

Comment: code? links? anything? In here you should post something, what you have tried, links you have visited... Don't ask for code ridiculously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking into this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Routes)

> A DirectionsRoute contains a single result from the specified origin
>   and destination. This route may consist of one or more legs (of type
>   DirectionsLeg) depending on whether any waypoints were specified.

[EDIT]

Google Maps Directions API v3 for Android provide routes in the [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1).

So you can try something as follows:
[android-draw-route-map-between-two-geopoints](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass latitude and longitude to this to get route directions for two points

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr="+ latposition + ","+lngposition;
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```